# How grupped array of objects on the property in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, grouping

I have a json data. How can I group objects by dates so that the date goes as a new object, and data that has the same date are recorded in persons. Below is the source and desired view
Maybe someone will throw an example, and then I'll finish it myself.

This my source json

```
[
  {
    "Info": [
        { 
            "age": "26" 
        }
    ],               
    "Date": "2020-08-14"

  },
  {
      "Info": [
          {
              "age": "23"                
          }
      ],          
      "Date": "2020-08-14"

  },
  {
      "Info": [
          {
              "age": "30"                
          }
      ],               
      "Date": "2020-08-15"

  }
]
```

This my desired json

```
[
   {
      "name": "2020-08-14",
      "persons": [
        {
            "Info": [
                { 
                    "age": "26" 
                }
            ],        
            "Date": "2020-08-14"
            
        },
        {
            "Info": [
                {
                    "age": "23"                
                }
            ],        
            "Date": "2020-08-14"
            
        }]
    },
    {
       "name": "2020-08-15",
       "persons": [
            {
                "Info": [
                    {
                        "age": "30"                
                    }
                ],        
                "Date": "2020-08-15"                
            }
        ]
     }    
   ]
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate the result-data. Iterating over the objects and look if is in the accumulated result object there exists a property with this date. If not create it and add a new object in it with the name-date and a person-property with an empty array. After this add in both cases the hole object to the person array.
At last get the [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the desired array out of the result-object.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "Info": [
        { 
            "age": "26" 
        }
    ],               
    "Date": "2020-08-14"
  },
  {
      "Info": [
          {
              "age": "23"                
          }
      ],          
      "Date": "2020-08-14"
  },
  {
      "Info": [
          {
              "age": "30"                
          }
      ],               
      "Date": "2020-08-15"
  }
];

let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (acc[cur.Date]=== undefined) {
        acc[cur.Date] = {name: cur.Date, persons: []};
    }
    acc[cur.Date].persons.push(cur);
    return acc;
},{}));
console.log(res);
```